# Iphone substring causing memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, substring

Im just wrapping up my app, so im onto the stage of running instruments to identify leaks in the app. Ive come across a leak that I cannot work out why it is being registered as a leak.

I have the following lines for example:

```
NSString *imageType = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[loopString substringToIndex:[loopString rangeOfString:@"</IMAGE>"].location]] autorelease];
imageType = [imageType substringFromIndex:[imageType rangeOfString:@"<IMAGE>"].location + :@"<IMAGE>".length];
```

So basically all im doing is pulling out a section of the "loopstring" and putting that into the imagetype string than just cutting off the trailing fluff of the string using the SubstringFromIndex method.

When I run instruments it says "NSCFString substringwithRange" leak. It highlights the second line:

```
imageType = [imageType substringFromIndex:[imageType rangeOfString:@"<IMAGE>"].location + :@"<IMAGE>".length];
```

I would think the substringFromIndex method should return a string that is automatically added to the autorelease pool.

Any ideas on where im going wrong?

Thanks

Following is the refactored code:

```
- (void)SetupTop10:(NSString *)Top10Data
{
while (Top10Data != @"") {
    NSLog(Top10Data);
    if ([Top10Data rangeOfString:@"</TOP10ENTRY>"].location == NSNotFound){
        Top10Data = @"";
    }
    else
    {

        NSString *loopString = [Top10Data substringToIndex:[Top10Data rangeOfString:@"</TOP10ENTRY>"].location + 13];
        Top10Data = [Top10Data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:loopString withString:@""]; 

        //NOW CREATE A RECORD FOR THIS ITEM
        NSString *imageType = [loopString substringToIndex:[loopString rangeOfString:@"</IMAGE>"].location];
        imageType = [imageType substringFromIndex:[imageType rangeOfString:@"<IMAGE>"].location + 7];
        NSString *displayText = [loopString substringToIndex:[loopString rangeOfString:@"</DISPLAYTEXT>"].location];
        displayText = [displayText substringFromIndex:[displayText rangeOfString:@"<DISPLAYTEXT>"].location + 13];
        NSString *link = [loopString substringToIndex:[loopString rangeOfString:@"</INTERESTID>"].location];
        link = [link substringFromIndex:[link rangeOfString:@"<INTERESTID>"].location + 12];
        [Top10Images addObject:imageType];
        [Top10Links addObject:link];
        [Top10s addObject:displayText];
        Top10RowCount = Top10RowCount + 1;
    } 
}

[self.Top10Table reloadData];
Top10Table.hidden = NO;
loadingLabel.hidden = YES;
loadingIndicator.hidden = YES;
```

}

//******************

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to actually make a copy of the `Top10Data` parameter since you are possibly altering it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look leaky. But why

```
NSString *imageType = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
             [loopString substringToIndex:[loopString
                                             rangeOfString:@"</IMAGE>"].location]
         ] autorelease];
```

if you effectively get the same with

```
NSString *imageType = [loopString substringToIndex:[loopString
                                             rangeOfString:@"</IMAGE>"].location];
```

with half the memory usage?

Comment: Sorry this was my first app so there is a still bit of hacky code left.

But that doesn't explain the reason why it should be leaking.

Comment: And also the second line should be:

    imageType = [imageType substringFromIndex:[imageType rangeOfString:@"<IMAGE>"].location + @"<IMAGE>".length];

Comment: you must realize that instruments is also just a tool, which can make mistakes. Keeping code clean and tidy helps preventing them. try changing `@"<IMAGE>".length` to `7`. Are you sure there's not other hacky code around these lines?

Comment: Yeah i just refactored the code removing the initwithstring and i also changed the @"<IMAGE>".length to 7 but still the problem persists.

Comment: Please update your question with the current code, so we all know what we're talking about. Please also tell what happens with imageType after these lines.

Comment: Hi mvds, I posted the updated code in the question. All im doing is looping through a string and putting the entries into MutableArrays.

Comment: Are the mutablearrays properly released?

Comment: Yeah the arrays are released in the dealloc.

Comment: Then there is no memory leak, based on the information you give here.

Comment: You've refactored it away, but for the record: @"String".length is not proper Objective-C, since length is *not* defined as a property. It should be [@"String" length]. This is (obviously) not the cause of your leak, but it is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Leaks will tell you where the leaked memory was *allocated*. If you click around (there's a right-arrow icon by the memory address, I think) then you can look at all the allocations/retains/releases for that addresses.

In this example, Leaks will point you to the first line, when it's the fifth one that "leaks" (actually it's a missing release in dealloc/on assignment that leaks):

```
NSString * s = [someString substringFromIndex:1];
[myArray addObject:s];
// ...
NSString * s2 = [myArray lastObject];
instanceVariable = [s2 retain];
// ... and forget to release in dealloc
```

What does tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: do?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problem in the above code. Did you release `Top10Images` in your dealloc method?

Comment: Or possibly it was retained an extra time somewhere. Or perhaps the object was accessed out of Top10Images and retained an extra time somewhere. But the cause of the leak is going to be outside of the code provided.